# Two asterisk server connection issue

Tags: voip, asterisk, google-talk

We have two server named 'SERVER A' and 'SERVER B' and Gtalk is configured in both the servers.

When a user calls a Gtalk-Id(configured in the server SERVER A) then the call gets received in the server named 'SERVER A' which gets forwarded to server 'SERVER B' using the GTALK channel and then 'SERVER B' call a national number using the DAHDI channel.

The scenario is as follows( Flow of call ) :

---

### USER (gtalk channel) -- > SERVER A (gtalk channel )---- > SERVER B(DAHDI channel) -- > DESTINATION NUMBER

Now the issue is , when the user calls first server 'SERVER A' using the Gtalk-Id then a connection establishes between the user and the destination number as per the above scenario but when the caller i.e the user cuts the call from Gtalk then the callee (destination number) channel do not receive this hangup signal and the connection between server "SERVER B" and 'DESTINATION NUMBER do not hangup instead of that only connection between USER and SERVER A breaks.

The hangup signal send by the caller do not gets transefered from SERVER A to SERVER B and this hangup signal should also break the signal of DAHDI channel to the callee.

Please help us in maintaining the hangup signal from 'Caller' to the 'Callee' using this two channels.

============
Techinal Information :

### Extension used to call from 'SERVER A' to 'SERVER B' is as below :

### exten => s,n,Dial(gtalk/google_talk/abc@gmail.com

## Note: please note that calls are successfully establishing between the caller and the callee.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use iax or sip between serverA and ServerB, will be no any issues.

Comment: No, I want to do only through the above explained setup(gtalk). Is there anything you can suggest us.

Comment: If so, you have enable debug or contact google support. But it unlikly  that will work, becuase gtalk designed for google, not asterisk interconnection.

Comment: OK, if that the case, Can we send hangup signal from server A (from hangup extension)to Server B (calling context). In this way above problem will get solved.

Comment: Gtalk is  nto designed to call between servers. no, you can't do anything.